# argument exception was unhandled in sql connection

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am getting an error when I try to run my program which says -

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Initialiseringsstrengens format does not match the specification starting at index 0.
```

at `using (conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))`

the whole code for that -

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    string connstring = (@"Data Source=SINDALSQL\MSSQL14; Initial Catalog=OminiData; Integrated Security =True");
    string sql = ("SELECT Mærke, Model, Årgang, [Motor Type], Krydsmål, Centerhul, Møtrik, Bolter, Dæk, Fælge FROM Hjuldata");

    private void binddata()
    {
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            conn.Open();
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adp.Fill(ds, "Hjuldata");
            hjuldata.DataContext = ds;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: `sql` variable contains connection string, `connstring` contains sql query. it should be vice versa

Comment: you are using wrong string for connection..it should be `sql` not `connstring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window { 
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    string connstring  = (@"Data Source=SINDALSQL\MSSQL14; Initial Catalog=OminiData; Integrated Security =True");
    string  sql= ("SELECT Mærke, Model, Årgang, [Motor Type], Krydsmål, Centerhul, Møtrik, Bolter, Dæk, Fælge FROM Hjuldata");

    private void binddata() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,connstring)) {
            adp.Fill(dt);
            hjuldata.DataContext = dt;
        }
    }
}
```